# do i need to create mapping for all objects of json that i get?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

I have questions about rest kit.

do i need to create mapping for all objects of json that i get ? or i can provide mapping only fore some of this objects and restkit will work properly even if I did not create mapping for some objects that I am loading from internet?

for example there are this classes

```
@interface RKAUser : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* nameString;

@property (strong, nonatomic) RKCard* card;

@end



@interface RKACard : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* numberString;

@end



+ (RKMapping *)userMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKAUser
 class]];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"nameString"]];

    return mapping;
}
```

I have json where is information for about 20 users
 in this json there are all user information including  nameString and  his cards numberString.

but I create mapping only for nameString and did not create mapping for card

question for this example will be would this code work or it will crash maybe because I did not provide all mapping

another question

can i use restkit for mapping any json information or not? 
does information should be definitely from some kind of rest server or rest kit can map json information from any server? will it work if information is not from server?

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens...

Comment: yes I can test this. and will see what will be . but It need to be able to use rest kit without a server for this case. looks like it is possible to use rest kit without a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to implement properties that you used when creating your mappings.

JSON doesn't need to come from the server. You can take any JSON document, then parse it yourself and use `RKMapperOperation` with the result.

```
RKMapperOperation *operation = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedJSON mappingsDictionary:yourMappingsDictionary];
NSError *error = nil;
[operation execute:&error];
if (!error) {
   NSArray *result = mapper.mappingResult.array;
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer
this parsedJSON can be dictionary that contains arrays of other dictionaries? like the result when I do `code
NSString * dataString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *parsedJSON =[dataString JSONValue]; `

Comment: about implement properties  . do you mean @synthesize them or do you mean create mapping for them?

Comment: For JSON, yes NSDictionary or NSArray is expected for representation. You don't have to `@synthesize` properties, just need to define them if you use them in mapping. In your example you used `nameString`, so you'll need `nameString` property in your user class.